# Array adapter and ListView Showing wrong data

Tags: java, android

[image: The attached image is what both lists look like]I am trying multiple activities that obtain data from ArrayLists. I have written the layout files and the java files but now one of the activities is showing the ArrayList from another activity.

There is no error so I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

The first array and adapter:

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends  Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

    ArrayList<String> albums = new ArrayList<>();
    albums.add("Umqele");
    albums.add("We are friends");
    albums.add("Isiphithiphiti");
    albums.add("Scorpion kings");
    albums.add("Red");
    albums.add("Different world");
    albums.add("Irue");
    albums.add("Dirty Computer");
    albums.add("Anti");
    albums.add("Love Girls");

    ArrayAdapter<String>  albumsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, albums);

    ListView albumView = findViewById(R.id.albums);

    albumView.setAdapter(albumsAdapter);
}
```

The second:

```
 public class PlaylistActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlists);

    ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    lists.add("House");
    lists.add("MorningJams");
    lists.add("SundayTunes");
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lists);

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.playlist);

    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
```

Comment: Please add code showing how you initiate the activities and presenting them.

Comment: How it is possible without communicating between activities. can you post your output?

Comment: Seems not possible because your are not getting data in either activity from another activity and other thing your arrayList have method level scope.

Comment: @CodeWithVikas well It's happening, so I'm kinda stuck

Comment: it's hard to show what is happening because it is happenign when I  emulate. I was trying to log the albums ArrayList and see what's really in it but nothing shows on the logcat

Comment: You mean it is happening only with emulator case ?.
Let me try this.Meanwhile can you post screenshot of the activity screen

Comment: image attatched

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202347/discussion-between-codewithvikas-and-tebogo).

Comment: You can take Screen Capture using logcat window only no need take laptop screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output of your code. It runs as expected. Meaning different data in each Activity.

MainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String a[] = new String[4];

        playlist = findViewById(R.id.open_playlist_bt);
        album = findViewById(R.id.open_albumlist_bt);

        playlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaylistActivity.class));
            }
        });

        album.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlbumsActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

AlbumsActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String a[] = new String[4];

        ArrayList<String> albums = new ArrayList<>();
        albums.add("Umqele");
        albums.add("We are friends");
        albums.add("Isiphithiphiti");
        albums.add("Scorpion kings");
        albums.add("Red");
        albums.add("Different world");
        albums.add("Irue");
        albums.add("Dirty Computer");
        albums.add("Anti");
        albums.add("Love Girls");

        ArrayAdapter<String> albumsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, albums);

        ListView albumView = findViewById(R.id.album);

        albumView.setAdapter(albumsAdapter);

    }

    public void openPlasylistActivity(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, PlaylistActivity.class));
    }
```

Playlist Activity

```
public class PlaylistActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
        lists.add("House");
        lists.add("MorningJams");
        lists.add("SundayTunes");
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lists);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.play_list);

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```